# error: cannot find symbol class AdvertiseActivity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest

I'm new to Android app development so please be patient with me. I'm writing an app that gets the GPS location from Google Play services and then broadcasts the data over Bluetooth. I have a **LocationActivity** that gets the location, and an **AdvertiseActivity** that broadcasts the data.

My problem is that I'm having a hard time understanding the file structure in android apps, so I suspect my lack of understanding is why I'm getting the error.

Here is a snippet of **LocationActivity** where the error is:

```
@Override
public void onLocationReceived(Location location) {
    Intent i = new Intent(LocationActivity.this, AdvertiseActivity.class) //problem is here
            .putExtra("latitude", location.getLatitude());
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Why can't the compiler find AdvertiseActivity.class? Is something wrong with my manifest below?

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="AllowBackup,GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
    <activity android:name="com.android.app.LocationActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.android.app.AdvertiseActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: you are using android.intent.action.MAIN for both the activities, remove one of them, it will work prroperly

Answer (score 0):

You are using two activities as **MAIN** .From manifest, Remove:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />
```

From `AdvertiseActivity`'s activity tag. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

An Application can have only one android.intent.action.MAIN  in Startup Activity. In your LocationActivity you already defined so remove intent-filter from AdvertiseActivity.

```
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
```

so its like

```
<activity android:name="com.android.app.AdvertiseActivity"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove these lines from manifest

```
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
```

And keep only this line.

```
<activity android:name="com.android.app.AdvertiseActivity"/>
```